# Apache FOP as servlet doesn't update images

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, apache-fop

I have Apache FOP 1.0 built as a servlet, running in Tomcat 5.5 on Linux CentOS 5.7-64bit.

If I build a document with an image, this document is rendered OK. Then I update the image, and do another rendering. The rendered document has still the old image. I've verified that the PDF is rebuilt from scratch, but for an unknown reason it still shows the old image.

This doesn't happen if I run FOP as a standalone program. The cache of Tomcat seems to be disabled.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Solution:
In [Fop 1.0 documentation](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/graphics.html#caching) there is the following sentence:

> FOP caches images between runs. There is one cache per FopFactory instance. The URI is used as a key to identify images which means that when a particular URI appears again, the image is taken from the cache. If you have a servlet that generates a different image each time it is called with the same URI you need to use a constantly changing dummy parameter on the URI to avoid caching.
>
> The image cache has been improved considerably in the redesigned code. Therefore, resetting the image cache should be a thing of the past. If you still experience OutOfMemoryErrors, please notify us.
>
> If all else fails, the image cache can be cleared like this: `fopFactory.getImageManager().getCache().clearCache();`

I've added the instruction to the code of the servlet, and the problem seems to have disappeared.